# How to display screen by screen in terminal

Tags: command-line

I am searching some files in terminal but the files is too long, how can I view them screen by screen.

Comment: What do you mean by screen by screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe the command to `more`:

```
<command> | more
```

or if you want to go up and down the text (using arrow keys), pipe it to `less`:

```
<command> | less
```